# Intermittent error in SharePoint Online. “Unable to display this Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online

Intermittent error in SharePoint Online. After page refresh, Error disappears.

“Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

Correlation ID:e0ce0d9f-606b-9000-eb7d-7cfbc164ccb3

Comment: Is it a modern page or classic page? Also, how many webparts (OOB and custom build) are on the page? Did you tried opening other page?

Comment: Is it showing this error for all webparts? Or any particular webpart? For which webpart this error is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Add the site into trusted sites in IE.
3. Switch to another browser.
   If the issue still exists, you could submit a service request and provide the correlation ID of the issue.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you Amy_MSFT. First two steps didn't work. Raised case with Microsoft Support Team.